# Why is it wrong to use the C to modify the double of a binary file?

Tags: c

I wrote a function that reads the double value in the struct in the binary file, and computes the value, and then writes the computed double value into the binary file.

the struct is:

```c
struct logData{
    long logId; 
    char logDate[11]; 
    char logNote[20];  
    double charge;   
    double total;    
};
```

The function to read and modify the data `charge` is：

```c
long size = sizeof(struct logData);

void update(FILE* fp, int n){
    fseek(fp,(n-1)*size, SEEK_SET);
    struct logData thisLogData;
    fread(&thisLogData,size,1,fp);

    long offset = sizeof(thisLogData.logId)+sizeof(thisLogData.logNote)+ sizeof(thisLogData.logDate);
    double oldCharge = thisLogData.charge;
    scanf("%lf", &thisLogData.charge);
    fseek(fp, -size+offset, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&thisLogData.charge, sizeof(thisLogData.charge), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Lots of the struct:`logData` are stored in the binary file. The parameter:`n` represents the position of `logData`.

I successfully read out the previous value of `charge`(`oldCharge` in function `update()`). The initial value of charge is 20, I enter 40 in the `update` function. After successfully writing, I read the value of the `charge` and found that it is neither 20 nor 40 but a strange 32.55 (I kept two decimals).

I tried to modify `logDate` and `logNote` can be successfully modified (of course `offset` is different). Only the double value `charge` and `total` will have strange results.

What is the reason?

Comment: There is probably padding in the struct that you are not accounting for.

Comment: as @JohnnyMopp says you do not compute well the offset because of the padding (_holes_ between fields in the struct), the answers give you several ways to correct that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long offset = sizeof(thisLogData.logId)+sizeof(thisLogData.logNote)+ sizeof(thisLogData.logDate);
```

This is not the offset of the member. Structure members have padding. Use `offsetof`.

```
size_t offset = offsetof(struct logData, charge);
```

Answer (score 4):

You read a full *logData* you can modify the read element then write all of it, probably you have padding problem so the computed offset is wrong

```
bool update(FILE* fp, int n){
    struct logData thisLogData;

    if ((fseek(fp,(n-1)*size, SEEK_SET) == -1) ||
        (fread(&thisLogData,size,1,fp) == 1)) {
      ??? indicate error ???
      fclose(fp);
      return false;
    }
    if (scanf("%lf", &thisLogData.charge) != 1) {
      ??? indicate error ???
      fclose(fp);
      return false;
    }
    fseek(fp,(n-1)*size, SEEK_SET);

    return ((fwrite(&thisLogData,size,1,fp) != -1)
            & (fclose(fp) != -1); /* not && because have to close in all cases */
}
```

else use *offsetof* to only write the new value of *charge* without reading the element :

```
bool update(FILE* fp, int n){
    double d;

    if (scanf("%lf", &d) != 1) {
      ??? indicate error ???
      fclose(fp);
      return false;
    }

    if (fseek(fp,(n-1)*size + offsetof(struct logData, charge), SEEK_SET) == -1) {
      ??? indicate wrong n / file ???
      fclose(fp);
      return false;
    }

    return ((fwrite(&d,sizeof(double),1,fp) != -1) 
            & (fclose(fp) != -1)); /* not && because have to close in all cases */
}
```

---

Note : it is strange the function has to close the file but do not open it, it is more logical to not do the close here

Comment: Well spotted bug!

Comment: Now formally you should also do error checking on the fseeks and fwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `offsetof` to find out offset of a field within structure:

```c
#include<stddef.h>

long offset = offsetof(struct logData, charge);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote a function that reads the double value in the struct in the binary file, and computes the value, and then writes the computed double value into the binary file.

Note that binary files are inherently non-portable.  If you're manipulating a file that was created on the same machine, by another C program built by the same C implementation, then you should be OK, but otherwise both writer and reader need to pay a great deal of attention to binary compatibility concerns.

Even in that case, however, your code is making unsafe assumptions.  The offset of a structure member (other than the first) is not guaranteed to be the same as the sum of the sizes of the preceding members.  Structures may, and often do, contain padding between members and after the last member, and that will throw your computation off.

Although it is possible to compute the offset of a structure member, including in old C versions that do not have `offsetof()`, in this case I would recommend sidestepping the issue altogether by writing the whole structure back to the file, instead of just a single member:

```
    fseek(fp, -size, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&thisLogData, size, 1, fp);
```